# Sticky not working within a bootstrap column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my form sticky as the users scroll past the content beside it.

I've used this method many times, and it's always worked in the past. It's driving me insane, does anybody know why my form isn't sticking in this instance?

```css
.sticky-top {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1020;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-5">
      <!-- sticky -->
      <div class="sticky-top">
        <div class="card card__body box-shadow" style="background-color:green;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
              <div class="form-group service-form-group">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="name"></label>
                <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-12">
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      <h2>Placeholder</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working fine but not for small screen since you are using col-12

Comment: Very very strange. It's not working locally on screen size :S

Answer (score -1):

I removed some of the `column` classes and added a `row` to the placeholder grouping. This seemed to fix your issue of the form not sticking.

Try the following:

```css
.sticky-top {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1020;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div>
      <!-- sticky -->
      <div class="sticky-top">
        <div class="card card__body box-shadow" style="background-color:green;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
              <div class="form-group service-form-group">
                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="name"></label>
                <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
        <h2>Placeholder</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.